# Check for .NET 3.5 and enable if disabled

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-server-2012

I have a batch file that runs the following line:

```
dism /online /get-features /format:table | find "NetFx3"
```

If the output returns that NetFx3 is 'disabled' I want to enable it with the following command:

```
dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3
```

I'm not sure how to actually query the output and check for enabled/disabled though.

Comment: what if you directly run `dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3` without checking? Will this break the script?

Comment: Oddly, I did not think about running the 'enable' command if it was already enabled. I'll test ot on some devices and see what the output is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done easily using dot-net code.  As,

1. Start Dism process with appropriate argument.
2. Don't use ShellExecute.
3. Redirect Standard Output.
4. Read Standard Output.

**Vb.net Code :**

```
Public Function GetDismOutput() As String
        Dim Output As String = Nothing
        Dim SxsPath As String = "D:\Sources\sxs"
        Dim CmdParm As String = "/online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /All /Source:"""
        Dim Pinf As New ProcessStartInfo With {.FileName = SxsPath, .Arguments = CmdParm + SxsPath + """ /LimitAccess"}
        Dim Prc As Process
        Try
            Pinf.UseShellExecute = False
            Pinf.RedirectStandardOutput = True
            Prc = Process.Start(Pinf)
            Prc.WaitForExit(20 * 60 * 1000) '' Wait for 20 Minutes
            CmdParm = Prc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
        Return Output
    End Function
```

**C# Code :**

```
  public string GetDismOutput()
  {
        string Output = null;
        string SxsPath = "D:\\Sources\\sxs";
        string CmdParm = "/online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /All /Source:\"";
        ProcessStartInfo Pinf = new ProcessStartInfo {FileName = SxsPath, Arguments = CmdParm + SxsPath + "\" /LimitAccess"};
        Process Prc = null;
        try
        {
            Pinf.UseShellExecute = false;
            Pinf.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            Prc = Process.Start(Pinf);
            Prc.WaitForExit(20 * 60 * 1000); //' Wait for 20 Minutes
            CmdParm = Prc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        return Output;
    }
```

Where D:\Sources\sxs is the path of sxs folder.
The Output String will be like :

```
Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 6.3.9600.17031
Image Version: 6.3.9600.17031
Enabling feature(s)
The operation completed successfully.
```